# PDO ->prepare on mysql query won't work

Tags: php, pdo

I have a mysql query that I'd like to wrap-up like this: `$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM log");` Then, I execute it like this: `$sql->execute();` , now my question is why can't I use it into a: `foreach($dbh->query($sql) as $row)` loop ? When I try to get it to run into the foreach loop the loggin form does not read from the db anymore. If I remove the dbh->prepare statement it works just fine, but I wanted to block SQL Injection on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You need to [fetch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) the results first (after you execute the statement):</s>

```
$rows = $sql->fetchAll();
foreach($rows as $row){
  ...
}
```

---

`query()` expects string only (the SQL query). But you were passing the return result of `prepare()` to it, which is a  `PDOStatement` object.

`prepare()` is used in succession with `execute()`, not `query()`. It makes sense to prepare your statements when you have input parameters that you want to pass to `execute()`.

In short:

```
$stm = $dbh->prepare('SELECT...');
$stm->execute();
```

is equivalent to:

```
$stm = $dbh->query('SELECT...');
```

if you have no input parameters to send.

Comment: Thanks much (vote up), so when using "prepare" I have to fetch before looping through ?

Comment: Actually no. It seems that `PDOStatement` is traversable. Perhaps something is wrong in your query? Does it work if you `fetch` first?

Comment: Well, the way I had it before the "prepare" statement was like this: 1. $sql = "SELECT * FROM log"; 2. foreach($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {//somecode}; It worked just fine. Then just by adding the $sql = $dbh->prepare("mySQL code"); it stopped working.

Comment: Edited, it should make sense now

Answer (score 2):

You are using prepared statements `$db->prepare($my_sql_query)`. When you use prepared statements, you usually may have some variables binded to the query. For example

```
$my_query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=:user_id'
$prepared_statement = $db->prepare($my_query);
$prepared_statement->bindValue(':user_id', 123);
```

Now when you have binded your values you need to execute your query

```
$prepared_statement->execute();
```

When you execute the prepared statement it generates the actual sql code and then executes it in mysql. And then to retrieve the results you would execute

```
$record = $prepared_statement->fetch(); //if you want to get only one record from the table
$records = $prepared_statement->fetchAll(); // if you want to get multiple records from the table

foreach($records as $row) {
    // your code here...
}
```

If you're using `$db->query()` you should be able to get the results with the following code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT name, color, calories FROM fruit ORDER BY name';
foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
    print $row['name'] . "\t";
    print $row['color'] . "\t";
    print $row['calories'] . "\n";
}

// outputs 
// apple   red     150
// banana  yellow  250
// kiwi    brown   75
// lemon   yellow  25
// orange  orange  300
// pear    green   150
// watermelon      pink    90
```

(taken from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php))

There is a big difference between the methods `query` and `prepare`:

1. `query` method will directly execute the sql code you've entered
2. `prepare` will "prepare" your sql code. This process replaces all params in the sql code with some actual values (i.e. `SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=:user_id` will become `SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=1`). Thus, when you use prepared statements you need to do `execute` so that the code is send to mysql.

Comment: Hi tftd, thanks for your answer. Yes, I do, but I was afraid that just leaving the MySQL query unwrapped would be less safe than passing it through a PDO::"prepare" statement to avoid potential MySQL-injection attacks.

Comment: Yes, using prepared statements are better in all cases. They prevent sql injection and are good practice.